# How to install vala app menu on fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, compiling, dnf, cmake

I browsed very much on internet and I followed [This website](https://gitlab.com/vala-panel-project/vala-panel-appmenu) .

**And I got errors and warnings .**

```bsh
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Error: The source directory "/home/superusr/vala-panel-appmenu" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI
```

Comment: Please add the error message to your question, we can't help you without the error.

Comment: I updated question

Comment: So, what directory are you in when you launch `meson`?  What is your full `meson` command?

Comment: I followed cmake but later , on this official repo of Konstaint ,  I opened this issue - https://gitlab.com/vala-panel-project/vala-panel-appmenu/-/issues/335 and he changed cmake to meson . And I used this command and got this output - https://pastebin.pl/view/ea393d34

Comment: OH SORRY I FORGOT TO ADD PLUGIN ON MY PANEL